# how can i display stars in an outline of a circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

So i have this code, it creates some tiny stars, how can i make them come in order from the left like come one by one and form an outline of a circle in the center of the page, also how can i make the stars like the normal stars with 5 corners, and how can i make the size much bigger.

```css
.stars {
  --num: 10;
  /* the number of stars */
  --w: 50vmin;
  width: var(--w);
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  position: relative;
  left: 100%;
  /* out of view to start with */
  transition: left 2s;
  color: #FFD700;
}

.stars.show {
  left: 0;
}

.stars>* {
  --starw: calc(var(--w) / var(--num));
  width: var(--starw);
  height: 50%;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - (var(--starw) / 2));
  transform: rotate(calc(var(--n) / var(--num) * 360deg));
  transform-origin: 50% bottom;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

.stars>*::after {
  content: '*';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  font-size: var(--starw);
}

.stars *:nth-child(1) {
  --n: 1;
}

.stars *:nth-child(2) {
  --n: 2;
}

.stars *:nth-child(3) {
  --n: 3;
}

.stars *:nth-child(4) {
  --n: 4;
}

.stars *:nth-child(5) {
  --n: 5;
}

.stars *:nth-child(6) {
  --n: 6;
}

.stars *:nth-child(7) {
  --n: 7;
}

.stars *:nth-child(8) {
  --n: 8;
}

.stars *:nth-child(9) {
  --n: 9;
}

.stars *:nth-child(10) {
  --n: 10;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.querySelector('.stars').classList.add('show');">CLICK ME</button>
<div class="stars">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

So i have this code, it creates some tiny stars, how can i make them come in order from the left like come one by one and form an outline of a circle in the center of the page, also how can i make the stars like the normal stars with 5 corners, and how can i make the size much bigger.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Comment: i made it come from the right  side and it goes to the left top corner i want to change that to go from the right side and go to the center

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

- `content: '★';` to use the five-point star
- `color: #FFD700;` to use your golden color
- `font-size: 2.5rem;` to increase the size

Here's a running example:

```css
.stars {
      --num: 10;
      /* the number of stars */
      --w: 50vmin;
      width: var(--w);
      aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
      position: relative;
      left: 100%;
      /* out of view to start with */
      transition: left 2s;
    }

    .stars.show {
      left: 0;
    }

    .stars>* {
      --starw: calc(var(--w) / var(--num));
      width: var(--starw);
      height: 50%;
      top: 0;
      left: calc(50% - (var(--starw) / 2));
      transform: rotate(calc(var(--n) / var(--num) * 360deg));
      transform-origin: 50% bottom;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .stars>*::after {
      content: '★';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      font-size: var(--starw);
      color: #FFD700;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
    }

    .stars *:nth-child(1) {
      --n: 1;
    }

    .stars *:nth-child(2) {
      --n: 2;
    }

    .stars *:nth-child(3) {
      --n: 3;
    }

    .stars *:nth-child(4) {
      --n: 4;
    }

    .stars *:nth-child(5) {
      --n: 5;
    }

    .stars *:nth-child(6) {
      --n: 6;
    }

    .stars *:nth-child(7) {
      --n: 7;
    }

    .stars *:nth-child(8) {
      --n: 8;
    }

    .stars *:nth-child(9) {
      --n: 9;
    }

    .stars *:nth-child(10) {
      --n: 10;
    }
```

```html
    
    <button onclick="document.querySelector('.stars').classList.add('show');">CLICK ME</button>
    <div class="stars">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this only partially answers the question.

Comment: how can i make it come from the left and one by one and make an outline of a circle in the center

Comment: I'm not fully understanding what you mean, could you explain it in a bit more detail/ maybe with an example? And I will update the code accordingly

Comment: rn when you press the button the stars come from the left side i want it to come from the right side, also when its dont moving it should be in the center, like the stars come from the right side and stop moving when its in the center of the page, also like the stars hsould come one by one like one star comes then another etc and they form an outline of a circle in the center of the page. @Lissy93

Answer (score 0):

For the color add color: ##FFD700 to stars>* . For the shape, you can use an SVG.